# SKPaymentTransaction always fail

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm building an app with Swift and I just added StoreKit support.
There is only consumable products in my app.

AppDelegate follows the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol and here's my `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` method:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction in transactions as [SKPaymentTransaction] {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
            case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchasing:
                println("purchasing")

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
                println("payment done")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

            case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
                println("payment failed")
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

            default:
                println("nop \(transaction.transactionState)")
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a test user in iTunes connect and so on and everything works fine except all transactions failed whatever I do.

Transactions go to purchasing state and then failed, even if I confirm the transaction in simulator.

Any idea why this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: As you discovered, in app purchase is not available on the simulator but you should implement code to check if the store is available as purchasing can be disabled on a real device too

Comment: Thanks for your comment, how should I do that?

Comment: You should check `canMakePayments` on your payment queue, but as per @w0mbat's answer (and a quick test) it seems that this now reports YES in the simulator, even though transactions won't go through

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official word from Apple is that StoreKit doesn't work in the simulator.

These days, with an iOS 8 target in the current simulator quite a lot of it does work, like fetching the list of products, or putting up the purchase confirmation dialog. However the final purchase still fails in the simulator, and that appears to be deliberate on Apple's part.

Comment: I am facing this issue on device. In day it is working fine and now I get continuosly failed...

Answer (score 1):

You Can Test IAP in Your ios6.1 Simulator and yes iOS 8.0 Simulator Also Gives You Response Alert But DoesNot Provide Purchase Functionality In Simulator

Answer (score 0):

As @w0mbat says the hole flow is working now except for the actual confirm transaction, in order to manage this you can do the following

Import target conditionals header

```
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
```

Modify your failed transaction method

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
   {
        if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR  && DEBUG && (transaction.error.code==0))
        {
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            return;
        }
        ...
   }
```